# IIS SMTP incoming messages stuck in \inetput\mailroot\queue\ and not going to \inetpub\mailroot\drop\

Tags: windows, iis, smtp

My ASP.NET app is not receiving incoming email because the incoming .EML files are all stuck in queue.

I setup a new AWS EC2 virtual Windows Server 2016 IIS SMTP, and started it.  But all the incoming .EML files are stuck in the queue.
I then set file permissions of drop\ to "Everyone" full access.  No effect.

Comment: Could you please share the SMTP details setting snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM: Missing SMTP alias domain for each incoming email domain (eg. MyWeb.com)

SOLUTION: Windows server > control panel > Admin tools > IIS 6 Mgr > local computer > SMTP Virtual Server > Domains > right-click > New > Alias > each incoming domain (eg. MyWeb.com)